# call jquery chosen's trigger method from popup window

Tags: jquery, popup, jquery-chosen

I was driven by this problem to crazy, I am working on an asp.net web project, so I use facebox to make a page popup, the popup page is only a confirmation, users need to click confirm button, then I need to delete an option from a select which has been used jquery chosen.js to translate. 
On the main page, the select

```
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

On the popup page, I call a js method

```
        var acqlistSelect = $("#selectId", window.parent.document);
        var acqlistSelectIndex = acqlistSelect.prop("selectedIndex");

        $("#selectId option", window.parent.document).eq(acqlistSelectIndex).remove();

        acqlistSelect.chosen({disable_search: true}).change();
        acqlistSelect.trigger("liszt:updated");
```

And you know the chosen selected li has not been deleted. But if I call the similar method on the main page itself, like

```
     var acqlistSelectIndex = $("#selectId").prop("selectedIndex");
     $('#selectId option').eq(acqlistSelectIndex).remove();
     $('#selectId').chosen().change();
     $("#selectId").trigger("liszt:updated");
```

It works perfectly, the chosen select li has been removed.  Any idea. really appreciate it.

Comment: I haven't used Facebox but would guess it shows content in a div within the same DOM as that of the main page content. If so then `window.parent.document` is wrong; the window and the document are the same window and the same document as the main page. Similarly, there will be only one javascript global environment. True popup windows are hardly used these days.

Comment: Thanks, Beetroot, I have used `window.parent.document` to update other elements which are not jquery chosenized. They all work, and I have use jquery method `.closest()` to get the object of `selectID`, the same problem,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK,I have figured out how to do that, I added some breakpoint on the chosen event liszt:updated, and i found out when I run the code

```
    var acqlistSelect = $("#selectId", window.parent.document);
    var acqlistSelectIndex = acqlistSelect.prop("selectedIndex");

    $("#selectId option", window.parent.document).eq(acqlistSelectIndex).remove();

    acqlistSelect.chosen({disable_search: true}).change();
    acqlistSelect.trigger("liszt:updated");
```

Actually it didn't hit the breakpoint, but the js method on the main page did it, so I call

```
parent.UpdateMethod();
```

from the popup page, and it did hit it. good. Done